# Integer multiple of eigenvector is an eigenvector with the same eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If we define an eigenvalue $\lambda$ to be a non-degenerate eigenvalue then, by definition, the eigenvalue has only one eigenvector, say $\psi$. An integer multiple of $\psi$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Why is this correct? Would a non-integer scalar multiple of the eigenvector also be an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$?

Comment: "then, by definition, the eigenvalue has only one eigenvector" - No. Then, by definition, the eigenspace is 1-dimensional.

Comment: An eigenspace is a subspace. In particular, any scalar multiple is an eigenvector with the same eigenvalue, as hff1 just said.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thank you. Of course the non-degenerate eigenvalue corresponds to the 1D eigenspace spanded by its eigenvector (thus any scalar multiple of that eigenvector is within this subspace). If we apply a given operator, say $A$, to the eigenvector, say $v$, then this transformation is equal to $v$ times (scaled by) the eigenvalue, say $\lambda$, hence $A \psi = \lambda \psi$.

Comment: Yes, thank you.